# How to set an objects pos with a different variable than the original

Tags: javascript, arrays, geometry

I am currently making a script where I should be able to pick up some circles, and currently, I am using 3 circles of a similar name, circle1, circle2, and circle3.

For some reason it doesn't do what it's supposed to and let me pick the circles up, can someone please help me? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
var NUM_CIRCLES = 3;
var RADIUS = 30;

var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

var circle1;
var circle2;
var circle3;

var val1 = new Array();
var val2 = new Array();
var val3 = new Array();
var val = new Array();
var vaal = 0;

var changeInX = 0;
var changeInY = 0;

function start(){
    drawCircles();
    setTimer(dragAndDrop, 10);
}

// This function draws a number of random colored circles at random points 
// on the screen based on the variable NUM_CIRCLES
function drawCircles() {
    circle1 = new Circle(RADIUS);
    var x1 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getWidth() - RADIUS);
    var y1 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getHeight() - RADIUS);
    circle1.setPosition(x1, y1);
    circle1.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    add(circle1);
    
    circle2 = new Circle(RADIUS);
    var x2 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getWidth() - RADIUS);
    var y2 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getHeight() - RADIUS);
    circle2.setPosition(x2, y2);
    circle2.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    add(circle2);
    
    circle3 = new Circle(RADIUS);
    var x3 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getWidth() - RADIUS);
    var y3 = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getHeight() - RADIUS);
    circle3.setPosition(x3, y3);
    circle3.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    add(circle3);
}

function dragAndDrop(){
        mouseDragMethod(mouseDrag);
}

function getMouseXY(e){
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
}

function mouseDrag(){
    val1 = [];
    vaal = mouseMoveMethod(getVariableXAndY);
    val1.push(vaal);
    val2 = [];
    val2.push(mouseMoveMethod(getVariableXAndY));
    val3 = [];
    val3.push(mouseMoveMethod(getVariableXAndY));
    val = [];
    val.push(val1, val2, val3);

    var mouse = new Array(mouseX, mouseY);
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 2){
        mouseDownMethod(getMouseXY);
        if (((val[i]) + RADIUS) >= (mouse[i]) && (((val[i]) - RADIUS) < 
(mouse[i])) && (((val[i + 1]) - RADIUS) < (mouse[i])) && (((val[i + 1]) + 
RADIUS) > (mouse[i]))){
            stopTimer(dragAndDrop);
            setTimer(waitForMouseMove, 10);
        }
    }
}

function waitForMouseMove(){
    mouseMoveMethod(mouseMoveBall);
}

function mouseMoveBall(){
    var oldMouseX = mouseX;
    var oldMouseY = mouseY;

    mouseMoveMethod(getMouseXY);

    if(oldMouseX > mouseX){
        changeInX = oldMouseX - mouseX;
    } else if(oldMouseX < mouseX){
        changeInX = mouseX - oldMouse;
    } else if(oldMouseY > mouseY){
        changeInY = oldMouseY - mouseY;
    } else{ 
        if(oldMouseY < mouseY){
            changeInY = mouseY - oldMouseY;
        }
    }
}


function getVariableXAndY(variable) {
    var xAndYCords = [variable.getX(), variable.getY()];
    return xAndYCords;
}
```

Thanks
-Lerb_games

Comment: Hi, please provide the desired output and what you get currently

Comment: Hello, I currently do not get any output but I would like to get the circle to detect when the mouse is dragging it and follow the mouse until the mouse is no longer dragging it.